# can I serialize Android-Class Instances outside an Android App?

Tags: java, android, windows, serialization, jvm

I would like to serialize AndroidCLass Instances from a native Java Application.

I have a Java-Application running on a local machine with several tasks.
One of the task is to serialize Android-Class Instances from specific data.

My solution so far is the following:
- Do some tasks thats can be done locally.
- automatically upload an Android-App (adb install apk) to a device and push specific data to the device too (adb push file).
- start the app, which creates Android-Class Instances and serialize them into a file.
- download the file from the apps device to local (adb pull file)
- do further stuff with the local file with my locally running java application.

Is there any way to serialize Android-Class Instances from a Java-Application running locally on a pc ?

From my understanding this is inpossible, but probably there are some cracks out there, which will find a way to do this .

Actually when trying to instance an Android Class I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics
```

Thats probably logical, because how could a windows JVM interprete AndroidDevice Classes.

Any help on this ?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using modern, cross-platform data serialization approaches (XML, JSON, protobuf, Thrift, etc.)?

Comment: The reason is, that it must be very fast. I am serializing graphical objects. Using XML or JSON would slow down the load heavy, that I measured.